# ¿Cómo puedo convertir columnas a filas y filas a columnas en R? Es decir, convertir datos altos a anchos y viceversa

Tags: r

Tengo un df que básicamente se ve como en la figura y deseo en un primer paso convertir columnas a filas y luego filas a columnas, es lo que usualmente se dice convertir datos anchos a datos altos y viceversa, usualmente POWER BI y Tableau lo hacen fácilmente pero ahora necesito hacerlo en R para tener una única rutina.[image: mi data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En R también es sencillo de hacer. En este caso te presento la solución usando el paquete `tidyr`. Pero hay otras soluciones con r base (la función reshape) y con otros paquetes (el paquete reshape y reshape2).

Primero cargamos el paquete y creamos un data.frame con tus datos.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
 df<-data.frame(
   Proceso = c("Fabricacion","Materia prima"),
   enero = c(1,4),
   febrero = c(2,5),
   marzo = c(3,6)
 )
```

**Pasamos de columnas a filas**
Agregue la solución con `gather` pues es la que suelo usar. Sin embargo, en el proceso me di cuenta que en nuevos códigos es recomendable usar `pivot_longer` en su lugar. Pues aunque `gather` sigue estando disponible ya no está en desarrollo.

```
 df_l<-df%>%gather(key="Mes",value="Valor", -Proceso)%>% 
   #Ordenamos por proceso
   arrange(Proceso)
 df_l
        Proceso     Mes Valor
1   Fabricacion   enero     1
2   Fabricacion febrero     2
3   Fabricacion   marzo     3
4 Materia prima   enero     4
5 Materia prima febrero     5
6 Materia prima   marzo     6

#Se obtiene el mismo resultado al usar la función pivot_longer
df%>%pivot_longer(-Proceso, names_to = "Mes", values_to = "Valor")
```

**Pasamos de filas a columnas**

```
 df_l%>%spread(Mes,Valor)
        Proceso enero febrero marzo
1   Fabricacion     1       2     3
2 Materia prima     4       5     6

#Usando pivot_wider inverso de pivot_longer
df_l%>%pivot_wider(names_from = Mes, values_from = Valor)
```

Comment: Al usar gather recibí el mensaje en R que ahora se debe usar la función `pivot_longer ()` en su lugar, así que usé esa y obtuve el mismo resultado, y para pasar filas a columnas usé `spread()` y funcionó, gracias.

Comment: Gracias. Agregue la solución a la respuesta Leyendo la ayuda de pivot_longer me doy cuenta es una actualización de gather que planea se más simple y eficiente. Y también tiene su inversa pivot_wider.